# Cant boot win7. Boot loader installed on SSD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I have 500gb hdd and 32gb SSD on my ASUS laptop UX32V

On HDD there was WIN7

On SSD I just have installed Ubuntu (/,/home,/swap and boot partition)

After all I realized that I have made a bad choice to make a boot partition on SSD because now i can boot only Ubuntu.

I have installed win7 recovery tool on my USB. When I run it i have to select os which I want to repair but in selection window win7 doesn't show up.

Can I reinstal boot loader to my HDD? what should i do?

```
> > karolis@karolis-UX32VD:~$ sudo lshw -C disk [sudo] password for karolis:    *-disk                  
>        description: ATA Disk
>        product: Hitachi HTS54505
>        vendor: Hitachi
>        physical id: 0.0.0
>        bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
>        logical name: /dev/sda
>        version: GG2O
>        serial: TE95113QKWMLSP
>        size: 465GiB (500GB)
>        capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
>        configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=4096 signature=957a0691
```

*-disk

> ```
>    description: ATA Disk
>    product: SanDisk SSD i100
>    physical id: 0.0.0
>    bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
>    logical name: /dev/sdb
>    version: 11.5
>    serial: 121600103561
>    size: 29GiB (32GB)
>    capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
>    configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=a8636661-170c-476f-81b8-e2d39c529c61 sectorsize=512
> ```

*-disk

> ```
>    description: SCSI Disk
>    product: xD/SD/M.S.
>    vendor: Generic-
>    physical id: 0.0.0
>    bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
>    logical name: /dev/sdc
>    version: 1.00
>    serial: 3
>    capabilities: removable
>    configuration: sectorsize=512
>  *-medium
>       physical id: 0
>       logical name: /dev/sdc
> ```

Answer (score 0):

try repairing grub via `boot-repair` booting into live usb of ubuntu, make sure repair windows boot files is checked under Advenced/Other Options. Than you'd be good to go.